# Extracting Email Attachments from Outlook 365 using Python

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments

Has anyone tried extracting email attachments based on some text in the subject?  If so how did you go about it? I'm ideally looking to save them all to a folder.

Thanks for the help!:D

Comment: Python module [attachment-downloader](https://github.com/jamesridgway/attachment-downloader) which uses module [imbox](https://github.com/martinrusev/imbox)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use Outlook Object Model to talk to the locally installed Outlook, create an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object, retrieve the `Namespace` object from `Application.GetNmaespace("MAPI")`, call `Namespace.Logon`. You can then retrieve the source folder (e.g. `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`), build an appropriate query and use it to call `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` (`Items` comes from `MAPIFolder.Items`). Once you have the matching message, loop through its attachment (`MailItem.Attachments`) and save them (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`).